# Hotkey script manager for Mac?

Tags: macos, automator, services

I always forget keyboard shortcuts to scripts I write (or sometimes the keyboard shortcuts I use don't work in a certain application). I'm looking for a service that I can remedy this by allowing me to use a certain hotkey, which brings up a window which allows me to write the first part of the name of one of my scripts (say, get_date, which just returns today's date in mm-dd-yy format), and it allows me to then invoke it for the functionality I need. I can't seem to find this, and I'm getting ready to embark on writing my own if I can't find one. Anyone know where to find something that I can use to do this?

Answer (score 2):

[Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/) can at least get very close to what you want. You do need the Powerpack license to use workflows in it (~£19).

It is somewhat manual, but to me it doesn't seem too cumbersome...

Give each script two triggers: `Keyword trigger` and `Hotkey trigger` and [you can then write what the shortcut is in the subtext field of the `Keyword trigger`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RWCv.png) (for example). This way [every time you use the keyword trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loAeX.png) ...probably because you forgot the shortcut, you still get a reminder of what the shortcut key combo is.

<sup><sub>Because the keyword I chose was similar to the Date and time preferences, it shows up too, but Alfred does adjust the order based on use, so after first use, the script would show up above the preferences given that I've never opened date and time preferences through Alfred. [You can also exclude files from showing up in Alfred.](https://www.alfredforum.com/topic/1412-excluding-folders/) For example,
 I got a workflow that opens dropbox folder... so I excluded Dropbox.app from Alfred because it is set to open on startup so I have no need to open it through Alfred.</sub></sup>

<sup><sub>Obviously every time you change the shortcut, you have to edit the subtext too.</sub></sup>

---

If you want to trigger automator workflow from alfred, I believe this is still the best method: [link](https://www.alfredforum.com/topic/1328-how-to-programmatically-execute-automator-workflows-and-service/). It's been a while since I looked into it so there is a good chance my info on this is outdated.

Comment: This is not super related to the question... but I just wanted to mention that Alfred also has `File filter`, which works like the `Keyword trigger`. Except you invoke the file filter with a keyword and then you give it an argument that is the file name (This has a fuzzy search. Can't remember if it has to be enabled in the general settings or something. ). I use this for various Photoshop and Illustrator scripts in specific folders. It's pretty easy to setup. [I write a keyword `.ps` and then after a space I start writing for the filename.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsbTD.gif).

Comment: And likewise, just a note that Alfred is pure goodness in an app and everyone should have it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [FastScripts](https://red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) solves this, I've tried it before, maybe Alfred